# Connecting to heroku psql database from local server - getting ssl error

Tags: javascript, postgresql, express, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to connect to my postgreSQL database on heroku from my express app. This works fine when the express app is also deployed to heroku, but I can't connect to the database when running the express app locally.

```
const db = require('knex')({
  client: 'pg',
  connection: ${process.env.DATABASE_URL}?ssl=true,
});
```

I receive this error: `err: Error: self signed certificate`.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

So originally I was using a connection string, I changed to using this instead:

```
connection: {
    host: process.env.PRODUCTION_HOST,
    user: process.env.PRODUCTION_USER,
    password: process.env.PRODUCTION_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.PRODUCTION_DATABASE,
    ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }
  },
```

when I had `ssl: true` it would not work. But then I changed it to the above where `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false }` and it seems to work fine for now.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use

```
connection: {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
},
```

Comment: I still get the `err: Error: self signed certificate` even though I added `ssl: { rejectUnauthorized: false },` any ideas @skoll?

Comment: @J86 Hard to say. Is it possible the connection is initialized somewhere else with other settings? Or does the DB URL itself contain conflicting SSL settings? This _should_ be what you need.